# How do I ensure the social icons appear on all pages?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I coded a footer section using Advanced Custom Fields where the social icons had their own field labels, name and type. You can see the image below:

[image]

Now you see that it says Show this field group if Page is equal to Home and the logical approach would be to add "and Page is equal to About Us" and so on, but when I tried that it did not work. I am out of ideas as to how I can get this custom field to show up on all the pages of my website.

Below is what it should look like on all pages:

[image]

This is my footer.php file:

```
<?php

// Custom Fields
$modal_title            = get_post_meta(14, 'modal_title', true);
$modal_body             = get_post_meta(14, 'modal_body', true);
$modal_logo             = get_post_meta(14, 'modal_logo', true);

// Advanced Custom Fields
$twitter_username       = get_field('twitter_username');
$instagram_username     = get_field('instagram_username');
$facebook_username      = get_field('facebook_username');

?>

<!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <?php if(!empty($twitter_username)) : ?>
             <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twitter_username; ?>" target="_blank" class="badge social twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(!empty($instagram_username)) : ?>
             <a href="https://instagram.com/<?php echo $instagram_username; ?>" target="_blank" class="badge social instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(!empty($facebook_username)) : ?>
             <a href="https://facebook.com/<?php echo $facebook_username; ?>" target="_blank" class="badge social facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

          </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p>&copy; 2008-2017 Three Green Birds. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- DONATE
        ==========================================================================  -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <?php echo $modal_title; ?></h4>
                 </div><!-- modal-header -->
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><?php echo $modal_body; ?></p>
                    <?php echo $modal_logo; ?>
                 </div><!-- modal-body -->
              </div><!-- modal-content -->
           </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- modal -->



<?php wp_footer(); ?>

 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options: use a [Options Page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/) (if you have ACF Pro) or you can also [get the values from another post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/).

**Options Page**

First you create a settings page on your functions.php:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    acf_add_options_page();

}
```

Then on ACF you select that those fields belong to an options page and you get an options page on wp-admin.

To show the fields on the template you can use the same template functions but you have to add a second parameter:

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name', 'option'); ?></p>
```

**Get values from another post**

On ACF you would setup the fields in just one page. For example, on your Home page.

And on the second parameter of ACF template functions you add the ID of that page:

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name', 123); ?></p>
```

where 123 is the ID of the page where you setup the ACF fields.